# Drag and drop query browser

Tags: gratis, linux, open-source, mysql

Is there a drag and drop query browser's like this for free or linux (except for Navicat, which is not free)
 [image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Update] OP has idicated that this answers his question. I leave the others below, in case they are of any use to others in future.

[Valentina Studio Pro](http://valentina-db.com/en/valentina-query-builder) includes a visual SQL query builder and you can use most of its abilities within the free Valentina Studio on Windows, Linux and Mac OS X.

[image]

---

[FlySpeed SQL Query](http://www.activedbsoft.com/screenshots-querytool.html) has both a free, and a paid for ($34.99) version. It looks just like NaviCat and can run in Linux using Wine.

[image]

---

[Easy Query BUilder](http://easyquerybuilder.com/) is similar, and free. It doesn't mention Linux, but should be worth trying with Wine.

[image]

---

Also, read https://www.quora.com/What-are-some-good-visual-SQL-query-builders and do some Googling. Could you pelase help us by posting here what you decide to use? Thanks

Comment: but after installing fly speed in linux it says "Error creating object.  Please verify that the Microsoft Data Access Components 2.1 (or later) have been properly installed" what can i do ??

Comment: OIC. Sounds like its looking for ODBC connectors. All that I suggest is to try to find some & put them in the sam edirectory as the executable. Or, try one of the others. I am sure that you can easilly fdind suitable software just by Googling. Good luck

Comment: Please let us know which one you decide to use (accept an answer, or even post your own), as it will help others in future who search for the same thing

Comment: I tried all three software you mentioned above. but in FlySpeed SQL Query some installation problems in linux. and finally i tried valentina studio and it's good for me. thank u again @mawg

Comment: I have updated my answer. I left the others, in case someone is interetsed in the in future. You can accept my answer, or even post one of your own, which only mentions [Valentina studio free edition](https://valentina-db.com/en/get-free-valentina-studio), just to make it clearer. Welcome aboard; glad to have been of help

Comment: @Mawg Might be a good idea to split your answer, so it gets clear which one is the "accepted" recommendation. Not a "must", just a "consideration". Especially as candidates not running natively are often not much preferred (that's almost as recommending a Windows user Linux software to run in a VM ;) Side-note: Navicat isn't native either (at least it wasn't when I last checked it; it came bundled within its own Wine embedding).

Comment: To be honest, I am having doubts. @sampathwijesinghe when I look at the [comparison of Valentina Studio editions](https://valentina-db.com/docs/dokuwiki/v5/doku.php?id=valentina:products:vstudio:features_demo) it seems like the query builder is not included in the free version. Does this ***really*** answer your question?

Comment: @Mawg query builder not in the free version but there is query editor. no different in query editor. It is same as the query builder that shows in the your answer.